# Switch-case in AJAX callback not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've this code over here:

```
/* Creo la stringa da mandare alla pagina in PHP */
    var dataString = '&nome=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&importo=' + importo + '&telefono=' + telefono+ '&pagamento=' + pagamento + '&agenzia=' + agenzia + '&id=' + id;



    var form = $(this);
    var str = form.serialize(); 

    /* Cosa succede una volta cliccato il pulsante */
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "mail.php",  data: dataString, success: function() {

        switch(pagamento) /* A seconda del pagamento... */
        {   

            case "paypal": /* Se si paga con Paypal... */

            switch(agenzia)
            {
                case agenzia.indexOf('Gabbiano') >= 0:
                /* Inserisci paypal del Gabbiano */
                $('#div_'+type).html("<div id='form_send_message'>Gabbiano</div>", 1500);
                break;

                case agenzia.indexOf('Istantravel') >= 0:
                /* Inserisci paypal Istantravel */
                $('#div_'+type).html("<div id='form_send_message'>Istantravel</div>", 1500);
                break;

                case agenzia.indexOf('Globmaster') >= 0:
                /* Inserisci paypal del Globmaster */
                $('#div_'+type).html("<div id='form_send_message'>Globmaster</div>", 1500);
                break;  

                default: 
                alert('Non riesco a capire in quale agenzia si vuole pagare!');

                }break;

            case "bonifico": /* Se si paga con bonifico... */

            switch(agenzia)
            {
                case agenzia.indexOf('Gabbiano') >= 0:
                /* Inserisci paypal del Gabbiano */
                $('#div_'+type).html("<div id='form_send_message'>Bonifico Gabbiano</div>", 1500);
                break;

                case agenzia.indexOf('Istantravel') >= 0:
                /* Inserisci paypal Istantravel */
                $('#div_'+type).html("<div id='form_send_message'>Bonifico Istantravel</div>", 1500);
                break;

                case agenzia.indexOf('Globmaster') >= 0:
                /* Inserisci paypal del Globmaster */
                $('#div_'+type).html("<div id='form_send_message'>Bonifico Globmaster</div>", 1500);
                break;  

                default: 
                alert('Non riesco a capire in quale agenzia si vuole pagare!');

                }break;

            case "agenzia": /* Se si paga in agenzia... */
            switch(agenzia)
            {
                case agenzia.indexOf('Gabbiano') >= 0:
                /* Inserisci paypal del Gabbiano */
                $('#div_'+type).html("<div id='form_send_message'>Agenzia Gabbiano</div>", 1500);
                break;

                case agenzia.indexOf('Istantravel') >= 0:
                /* Inserisci paypal Istantravel */
                $('#div_'+type).html("<div id='form_send_message'>Agenzia Istantravel</div>", 1500);
                break;

                case agenzia.indexOf('Globmaster') >= 0:
                /* Inserisci paypal del Globmaster */
                $('#div_'+type).html("<div id='form_send_message'>Agenzia Globmaster</div>", 1500);
                break;  

                default: 
                alert('Non riesco a capire in quale agenzia si vuole pagare!');             

                }break;


            default: 
                alert('Non riesco a capire in quale agenzia o con quale mezzo si vuole pagare!');

        }
```

As you can see by going here ( http://sposi.vantravelgroup.com/default/index.php?id=1#rsvp ) and testing the form, when you click on the submit button nothing happens (while theorically it should replace the form with the `<div>` inside the switch-cases) but the `mail.php` receives something like:

> Example User, example@gmail.com, 34, 3462151720, [object HTMLDivElement], 80.20.3.52, http://sposi.vantravelgroup.com/default/index.php?id=1, Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36)

And the `$mysqli->query($newRow)` in `mail.php` is `FALSE` instead of `=== TRUE`

Anyone has an idea of what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should remove the inner switch/case `switch(agenzia)` and just use `if`-statements instead... Right now you're trying to use switch/case as if-statements anyway....

Comment: Gonna try that ASAP :)